# Webpage (in php) i.e Javascript websocket client is not connecting to Python Websocket Server

Tags: javascript, python, websocket, server, client

It is showing this:
WebSocket connection to 'ws://10.14.79.58:1030/websocket' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 404

This is my sample python server code for client:

```
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web
import tornado.websocket
from tornado.options import define, options, parse_command_line

#define(1020, default=8888, type=int)


class IndexHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.render("test.html")


class WebSocketHandler(tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler):
    def open(self, *args):
        print ("New connection")
        self.write_message("Welcome!")

    def on_message(self, message):
        print ("New message {}".format(message))
        self.write_message(message.upper())

    def on_close(self):
        print ("Connection closed")


app = tornado.web.Application([
    (r'/webscoket/', WebSocketHandler),
])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.listen(1030)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

---

This is my `php` file in which `js` is used for connection:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
<h1>This is connect file</h1>
<script>
var connection = new WebSocket('ws://10.14.79.58:1030/websocket');


        connection.onmessage = function (e) {
        //document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = e.data;
        alert("Connection to the websocket established!!");
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're getting a 404, which means the page you're trying to reach doesn't exist. Just a guess, but try adding slash at the end of `/webscoket/`.

Comment: You have a typo, and your server is listening for requests to `/webscoket/` instead of `/websocket/`